# Find all matches between two columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of part numbers in two columns.
Two objectives.

1. List all unique values between two columns in another column.
2. List all matches for each of the unique values.

Below is an example. I could list unique values between Columns 1 and 2 (see the formula in cell D2); however, I got stuck on extracting all possible matches. I tried the Let( ) function, but it would not give me the result as shown below. *There is no formula in cell E2, I manually entered values in columns E to I.*

Another way to define this problem is if A = B and B = C, then A = C.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CU0tDt03tzesZEYLwrHgClHfxd_ivoHnFTfAYNJMeXM/edit#gid=0

To get those unique values, we can do something a little simpler than what you've done:

```
=unique(tocol(A2:B))
```

where we use TOCOL to flatten the columns into one and then UNIQUE on that to find the unique values.  Where it gets tricky is the all possible matches, and we can solve that with lambdas and some recursion (lambdas and recursion are features of modern Excel, but they've been out for a while so hopefully this is compatible with your version).

```
=let(
  findMatches, lambda(
    in, 
    unique(reduce(, in, lambda(
      a, x, {
        a; 
        iferror(filter(B:B, A:A=x), "");
        iferror(filter(A:A, B:B=x), "")
      }
    )))
  ),
  getAllMatches, lambda(
    self, in, 
    if(
      counta(in)>=counta(unique({in; findMatches(in)})), 
      in, 
      self(self, unique({in; findMatches(in)}))
    )
  ),
  temp, transpose(getAllMatches(getAllMatches, findMatches(D2))),
  filter(temp, temp<>"", temp<>D2)
)
```

First, lambda is just a fancy way of saying that you're going to define a reusable internal formula.  For instance, LAMBDA(x, x+1) is a formula that will take x and return x+1.  Combined with LET, which allows us to define name/value pairs, we can define a lambda, give it a name, and reuse it.  For instance:

```
=LET(
  ourFunction, lambda(x, x+1),
  ourFunction(3)
)
```

will return 4.  So let's take a look at the first part of the LET formula I've given.

```
  findMatches, lambda(
    in, 
    unique(reduce(, in, lambda(
      a, x, {
        a; 
        iferror(filter(B:B, A:A=x), "");
        iferror(filter(A:A, B:B=x), "")
      }
    )))
  )
```

here I'm defining a formula `findMatches` and assigning a lambda (function) to it, and that function takes one argument: `in`.  To start with this will be something like `c` or `b` or one of the other unique values from Column D.  I'm using REDUCE to get a list of values.  REDUCE takes 3 arguments, the accumulator, the input value, and the lambda function.  In this case, I pass an empty value for the accumulator so it will be empty to start with, and I also pass the `in` argument, which is going to be a value or an array of values.  To start with this will also be one of the unique values from Column D.

Let's talk about literal array notation for a minute: `{}`.  `{1,2,3}` will create an array containing 1,2 and 3, and the separator used will determine if it's a vertical or horizontal array.  `;` is vertical and `,` is horizontal.  In this case, the REDUCE function is trying to create a vertical array, and that array is going to contain the acculumator (`a`) and it's also going to contain the values from column B where A matches our input value (`x`) and also the values from Column A where B matches our input value.

For instance, if we are using the value "c", then the output is going to be:

```
{
  "c";
  "b"; "d"; // the values from col B where col A is c
  "b"       // the values from col A where col B is c
}
```

and then it's wrapped in UNIQUE to remove the duplicates: `{"c"; "b"; "d"}`.

REDUCE can operate on an array, so here is where the recursion comes in. If we were to pass the outcome of `findMatches("c")`, which is `{"c"; "b"; "d"}` back to `findMatches`, then it will do the same thing again, except for each element of the input array.

So we define a second lambda to do that: `getAllMatches`.

```
  getAllMatches, lambda(
    self, in, 
    if(
      counta(in)>=counta(unique({in; findMatches(in)})), 
      in, 
      self(self, unique({in; findMatches(in)}))
    )
  )
```

A lambda can't call itself directly, so we give the lambda two arguments, one is itself and the other is the input values.  `getAllMatches` then takes the input values and calls `findMatches` with them, then checks to see if any new values were found.  If there were no new matches, then it returns the result.  If there were, however, it combined those matches with the input values and then calls itself again with the new values.

Finally, I transpose the values from vertical to horizontal.  FILTER returns a vertical array, so we've been keeping it that way internally, but you need the display to be vertical.  The transposed results are assigned to `temp`

```
  temp, transpose(getAllMatches(getAllMatches, findMatches(D2))),
```

and then finally we filter any blanks from the array:

```
  filter(temp, temp<>"", temp<>D2)
```

Blanks can happen if there are no matches found in one column or another in the FILTER function used by `findMatches`, and also the accumulator for REDUCE will have an initial empty element that we want to remove.

Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: This is amazing! Your solution works in Google Sheets but when I use the same Let formula in Excel it fails. My Excel version is up to date. For now, I can use Google Sheets but can you think of any reason why it is not working in Excel?

Comment: I can.  I was working in google sheets so I didn't think about it, but Excel doesn't fully support the literal notation.  It will work for static values, for instance {1,2,3} is valid in excel, but trying to use dynamic values will fail.  Excel has HSTACK and VSTACK instead.  Let me edit the answer.

Comment: hey, still looking at this.  Theoretically you can just replace something like `{x; y; z}` with `VSTACK(x, y, z)`, but while the modified function works in excel it only produces a single column, instead of all possible matches.  There's some small difference in the array handling between sheets and Excel somewhere, even though in theory they should be interchangeable.  I'll let you know when I figure it out.

Comment: Chris, did you find any way to make it work in Excel? I tried but no success so far.

Comment: I fixed one issue, but it's not 100% yet.  Will update you later.

Comment: Any progress you made to resolve it?